# How can I apply Excel 2007 template to an existing document?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, templates

I have an existing Excel document of which I want to apply a template with different headers/footers/orientation.  How can I do this?  From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/84010/apply-template-to-existing-word-document-and-excel-file) post, it looks like this can be done in Word.  But, there is no "Document Template" button in Excel like there is in Word.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to apply a template to an existing document in Excel.