# Replace style set for a Word file by another file's style set?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Let's say we have two Word files #01 and #02 which are formatted as style #01 and #02 accordingly.

How can we quickly replace styles in file #01 by the ones in file #02 quickly?

E.g. Styles such as Header 1, Header 2, Header 2, Normal and Table Grid of file #01 should be updated to be the ones defined in file #02.

**Style #01**

[image]

**Style #02**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's easiest is to just save one document as a style set and then apply that style set to the second document.

[image]

Once you save the style, open the second document, go to "Change Styles" drop-down and then "Style Set".  Look for the style template that you just created and click on it.

[image]

Comment: What version is your Word? I cannot find the "Change Styles" icon in 2013 and 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Open file #1 and attach file #2 as a template, then toggle **Automatically update document styles**. The exact steps to achieve this is defined [here](https://superuser.com/questions/84010/apply-template-to-an-existing-word-document-file).