# Style template that makes files update their style automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, templates

I am writing a book made of many files. I design each file with the same styles (e.g. for headings and text body). Suppose later I want to change some styles (e.g. the heading font size), and keep it consistent throughout the book, without having to open each file and change it manually (similar to a style file in LaTeX). Is there a way I can create such a style file, that I can update once, and automatically all the documents using it will update accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to use
[Word Templates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb),
using your own template in all the documents, so that when the template
changes, all the documents change automatically.

Your documents will need to defined with the new template.
For making it work, you will need:

- [Show the developer tab in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-the-developer-tab-in-word-e356706f-1891-4bb8-8d72-f57a51146792)
- In the developer tab, click "Document Template", Templates tab,
  enable "Automatically update document styles" and click OK
- To add the new template to an existing document as described in
  [Apply template to an existing Word document file](https://superuser.com/questions/84010/apply-template-to-an-existing-word-document-file)

The above modifications need to be done for all your documents.
If attaching the templates one-by-one to many documents is too painful,
and if you can cope with VBA, see the VBA macro in
[Batch Template Changes](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010338_Batch_Template_Changes.html).

Comment: Note that this still requires that the documents be opened at some point. The danger of this setting is that if the document can't find your template it will update using the styles in the user's normal template. Be sure to turn the option off before sending your document to someone else or opening on a different computer. See http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/sharing/willmyformatchange.html and http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TextReflow.htm. These are the writings of Word MVPs on problems that can arise with this setting.

Comment: This works, thanks! @CharlesKenyon thanks for the warning - I will keep that in mind.

Comment: One question: when I open the "Document Template" dialogue, I see the template path is an absolute path. Is there a way to make it a relative path, so that if I move the entire book to a different folder, the template link remains intact?

Comment: There is an undocumented feature of Word, that it searches multiple locations looking for the document template, starting with the document's folder. The solution is to keep the template and documents together in the same folder. I haven't tested this in the latest versions and can't testify that it still works.

Answer (score 1):

### Look also into theme fonts.

See [Changing Default Settings](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CustomizeNormalTemplate.htm#Word2007Font) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill and my writing on [Themes](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Themes). You can save a custom theme with your settings. If you use theme fonts for your headings and body text, you can change them in any document using the theme by making a change to the theme.

If the theme does not exist on someone else's computer, though, I can't predict the results.